# ChildEventListener causing IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm developing an application where people can send messages to each other. When I send a message to my recipient, the IndexOutOfBoundsException error occurs as described below

```
        --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: mychatapp.mychatapp.com.mychatapp, PID: 15377
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 7
        at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:427)
        at mychatapp.mychatapp.com.mychatapp.Activity.ChatActivity$9.onChildChanged(ChatActivity.java:575)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ChildEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:82)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6316)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
Application terminated.
```

my ChildEventListener

```
private void recuperarMensagens(){
    listaMensagens.clear();
    childEventListenerMsgs = mensagensReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Mensagem mensagem = dataSnapshot.getValue( Mensagem.class );
            String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            listaKeys.add(key);
            listaMensagens.add( mensagem );

            if (!listaMensagens.isEmpty() &&
                    listaMensagens.contains(mensagem)){

                DatabaseReference msgRef = databaseReference.
                        child("mensagens").child(idUsuarioDestinatario)
                        .child(idUsuarioLogado)
                        .child(key)
                        .child("visualizado");
                msgRef.setValue(true);

            }

            mensagensAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Mensagem mensagem = dataSnapshot.getValue(Mensagem.class);
            String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            int index = listaKeys.indexOf(key);
            listaMensagens.set(index,mensagem);
            mensagensAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Line 575 is

```
listaMensagens.set(index,mensagem);
```

How to fix this error?Thanks in advance

UPDATE:I think when a new item is added, it appears duplicate until exit and enter the screen again. The previous items are ok.

UPDATE 2:Fixed bug for duplicate items but problem persists

Comment: The code you shared always adds an item to the `listaKeys` and to the `listaMensagens` at the same time. So there is no way for them to get out of sync in this code. My best guess is that you're updating `listaKeys` or `listaMensagens` somewhere else, and are forgetting to update the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the error occurred mainly when I started an Intent and returned the activity. So I added listaKeys.clear() to the method onPause, and the problem was fixed.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    listaKeys.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to add an element to your array at index 10 , but your array size is 7 , so it throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` to fix it :

- if you are not sure about index's value , just add a size to your array :

  ```
  ArrayList<yourObject> array =new ArrayList<yourObject>(100);
  ```

or if you don't want to specifie a size just try to add element at an index superior by one to the size

```
int theIndex = listaMensagens.size() + 1 ; 
listaMensagens.set(theIndex,mensagem);
```

in that way it is ensured that the position 8 is accessed safely and there would be no exception.